# How do i use var_prompt module after tasks is started in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm new to an Ansible

simply i say, I wanna make a confirmation alert after tasks is started.

due to I have to use setup facts which is hosts addresses in my alert.

my process is below

1. to show hosts
2. to confirm that the users really wanna run next processes?
   [in this part I need to show hosts list]
3. to do something....

is there any way to resolve it?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Start and Step](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_startnstep.html) will do what you want assuming you don't have a lot of tasks in your playbook.

Run your playbook like:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml --step`

From the docs:
`This will cause ansible to stop on each task, and ask if it should execute that task.`

The tradeoff is that you're going to get prompted for every task, so this is really only suitable if the number of tasks is small. Also, do you really want to run your playbook interactively?

Comment: Oh @Konstantin Suvorov helps me out! thank for both!! and thank u for understanding my poor english!

Comment: Nope, I just need to ask users, the host IP is correct once

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [pause](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pause_module.html) module.

```
- pause: prompt="Make sure that {{my_custom_fact_ip_address}} is correct..."
```

Comment: thanks a lot 'bout your reply, here is another one... how can I get an anwer 'yes' or 'no' ? do i need to user 'when' module?

Comment: @변규섭 unfortunately there is no such option, you can only proceed or abort playbook execution with `ctrl+c`, `a`.

Comment: when I use a host, It works good, but when I have more than 2 hosts, It doesn't work for another host address. :(

Comment: @변규섭 yes, pause module is executed only once per play.